# How to read data of this format?

Tags: c, input, scanf

Each line in my input starts with a letter and then depending on the letter I have to either read exactly 1 number, or any amount of numbers between 0 and 3. Here's how I tried to do this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int args[3] = { 0, 0, 0 };
    char cmd;
    int filled;

    for(;;)
    {
        scanf("%c", &cmd);
        switch(cmd)
        {
            case 'a':
                scanf("%d\n", args);
                break;
            case 'b':
                filled = scanf("%d %d %d\n", args, args+1, args+2);
                printf("Read %d\n", filled);
                break;
        }
        printf("Args is: %d %d %d\n", args[0], args[1], args[2]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The problem with `a` is, after I write `a 1`, for some reason it waits for 1 more character, for example `a 1 2` outputs "Args is: 1 0 0", and it does so twice. I'm completely confused as to what's happening here.

The option `b` doesn't work either, my program is waiting for exactly 4 numbers (4, not 3, same problem as above).

Comment: If your input format is line-oriented, it's usually way better to read in entire lines (using `fgets()`), then parse that once in memory. This removes hidden complexity due to the `FILE *` stream's state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see, you need to remove the `\n` from the `scanf()` format string, like

```
 scanf("%d", &args[0]);
```

to read only a single `int`.

That said, in the second case, you need to modify like

```
filled = scanf("%d %d %d", &args[0], &args[1], &args[2]);
```

However, a more elegant and robust solution would be to use `fgets()` to read a complete line at a time and then tokenize as per the requirement.

Comment: That modification doesn't work, because now it allows for input like `a 1 a 2`. However, `fgets()` did the trick.

Comment: @Dunno 1) that is why `scanf()` returns a value 2) Always try to stick to `fgets()`, much, much better.

Comment: Will do from now on, didn't even know it was there.

Answer (score 0):

```
scanf("%d %d %d\n", args, args+1, args+2);
```

Remove the `\n` and it will work as you expect. When you put the `\n` in the format specification that tells the program to read in a `\n`. Thus the program does not see the enter key that you must enter at the end of the data.  If you don't type the enter key at the end scanf will continue to read input indefinitely, but not store anything past the given format specifier.

Russ

Edit: The previous answer is correct that a more standard way is to use `&args[0]`, `&args[1]`, etc, but the way you wrote it will work because c treats an array name as a pointer.

Comment: This approach will not work well.  On the next iteration of `scanf("%c", &cmd);`, that will make `cmd` --> `'\n'`.